# Run program with file in java

Tags: java

Okay so I'm doing homework for my AI class and the code I list below was given. All I need to do is modify it slightly but that's aside the point, I can do that. What I need help with is I was told I have to run the program with input from a file like this: ReflexRover < < filename >

When I run the program I can give it individual numbers that the default constructor accepts and everything is fine. But When I give it a file name it says failed to open. I don't know how to use eclipse that well so is there a special way I'm supposed to run the program to send it the file?

Note: there is no problem with the code itself

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.lang.*;

  /**
  * RovingSampleSensors: A class for reading sample perceptions from a file
  * and presenting them one at a time
   *
   * @author 
    * @version 1.1
   *
  * allowed stdin version of contstructor
   */

  public class RoverSampleSensor {
// File
private BufferedReader myFile;


/**
 * Creates Sensors object from file
 * @param filename The file that data is read from
 */
public RoverSampleSensor(String filename) {
try {
    myFile=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Ooops!  I can't seem to load the file \""+filename+"\", do you have the file in the correct place?");
    System.exit(1);
}
}

/**
 * Creates Sensors object from standard input
 */
public RoverSampleSensor() {
try {
    myFile=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Ooops!  I can't seem to read from the standard input!");
    System.exit(1);
}
}

/**
 * Gets the next sample perception
 * @return SamplePercept A SamplePercept object containing the percept
 */

public SamplePercept getPercept() {
String line;

try {
    line=myFile.readLine();
    if (myFile==null) {
    return null;
    } else if (line==null) {
    try {
        myFile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    myFile=null;
    return null;
    } else {
    return new SamplePercept(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Ooops!  I seem to have gotten an i/o error reading the file.");
    System.exit(1);
}
return null;
}

/**
 * Run a test of the reading routines, prints out all percepts of the file
 *
 * Usage: java RoverSampleSensor -file <filename>
 */

public static void main(String args[]) {
if (args.length!= 0 && 
    (args.length != 2 ||   (! args[0].equals("-file")))) {
    System.err.println("Usage: RoverSampleSensor -file <filename>");
    System.exit(1);
}
RoverSampleSensor rss=null;
SamplePercept sp;

if (args.length==0) {
    rss=new RoverSampleSensor();
} else {
    rss=new RoverSampleSensor(args[1]);
}
while((sp=rss.getPercept())!=null) {
    System.out.println("Percept: "+sp.value());
}
}

}
```

Okay allow me to refine my question. This is what I did: I click run, the console pops up, I can enter integers one by one no problem. I just need to know how to get the program to work when I do RoverSampleSensor . The file is already at the same level as my src. Every time I try it catches my exception and says ""Ooops!  I seem to have gotten an i/o error reading the file". I cant print the stack trace because I'm not supposed to change that part of the code. Am I not supposed to hit run before I try to send it the file? Is there a different way I am supposed to run it?

Comment: Add the stacktrace for the error you are seeing.

Comment: Can you tell what the error is? I'm thinking it's probably that it can't find the file due to path errors

Comment: You can go to run configurations in Eclipse and then modify the "arguments" tab. Insert `-file /path/to/file/file.txt`. This should pass the proper arguments to your code.

Comment: In the catch block, add e.printStackTrace() and update the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

If you are working under Eclipse and don't intend to export your project in a jar file, an easy solution is to put your file at the root of the project (at the same level of the folder src). If you do that, the path to the file will only consist in its name.

If you launch your program with a console command, you must provide the path to the file accordingly to the current folder in the console.